# Against what force are we doing work when we accelerate an electron?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In [vol. I, chapter 32, of The Feynman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html), Feynman says:

> If we take a charged body and accelerate it up and down it radiates
>   energy; if it were not charged it would not radiate energy. It is one
>   thing to calculate from the conservation of energy that energy is
>   lost, but another thing to answer the question, against what force are
>   we doing the work?

Then he says:

> this problem has never been solved.

Has this problem been solved since?

Comment: Quantum revolution: Qed: the jewel of physics, Volume 2

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: I edited it. There is some information on the subject there. Just do ctrl + F, then type in "Against what force are we doing work when we accelerate an electron?"

Comment: Forces are a classical concept, they don't exist in quantum field theory. Feynman knew better, but what he knew didn't quite make it in the best possible way into the lectures. Honestly... at this point in time they are not the best resource to learn physics, by far.

Comment: "if it were not charged it would not radiate energy" - How this will be truth? Every body radiates energy when get accelerated.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I find the lectures amazing; therefore, if you know of a resource which is better "by far", I would like to know what it is! note, that to beat Feynman it cannot just be more up to date, or more complete; it must also be as comprehendible, exciting and inspiring; there is little use for me in an impenetrable or boring book.

Comment: I have never gotten much out of Feynman's lectures. In terms of phenomenology they are very shallow, and in terms of theory they are, as in this case, oversimplifying, and sometimes outright misleading (also as in this case). That seems to be a general trait of American textbook authors and it's a pity that Feynman felt that he had to go there. The resource that you need is called "the library". The times when one book would be enough to teach you about a subject are over. You are not in high school anymore.

Comment: I think it is a very good question!!!

Comment: @CuriousOne, please don't patronize me; from my experience 9 out of 10 books are a waste of time so just sending one to the library doesn't seem helpful. also I humbly disagree with your opinion on feynman's lectures.

Comment: Feynman's lectures are great books in many ways - they are readable, have refreshing ways to explain things, are fun to read and contain insights hard to find in other textbooks. But they also have their flaws and omissions, as any textbook has. Reading other books to confront different viewpoints is a necessity.

Comment: Feynman answers the question in the case of an accelerated charged ball. The force is due to the delay action across the ball: the electrons inside the ball feel the electric field of other electrons with a tiny delay. The net electrostatic force is then non zero and opposed to the acceleration. So the force is electrostatic.     
In the case of one electron:  we can shrink the ball till only one electron remains. The nature of the force shouldn't change. But how does it happen?  
You need a model with a spread wave function for the electron but you can still use a classical electric field..

Comment: ..so the electron can feel its own field electric field when accelerated. One can do a simple model in one dimension. You start from a pure quantum state of the electron and the electric field. Then you accelerate the electron applying a translation operator...

Comment: Feynmans books are good; they don't rely on heavy formalism; if you like them you'll probably like Dr Tongs notes; though he also says that things have moved on since Feynmans notes; well it's been fifty years since he wrote them.

Comment: @curiousone: the Force might be fictitious - but it's still useful.

Comment: I never suggested that you should read every book in the library front to cover. YOU are the one who has to select what useful for you. I do, however, not think the Feynman lectures will do anything for you if you are interested in real physics, plain and simple. I would further suggest you stop listening to everybody who says anything about self-interaction in classical field theories. That's all overreaching classical nonsense that was made up before we had a better idea about what is really happening from quantum field theory.

Answer (score 3):

> Has this problem been solved since?

Not in the sense Feynman meant.

Approximate way to describe action of one charged part of body on another is known since Lorentz - the so-called Lorentz-Abraham-Dirac term.

What Feynman is getting at is this term works somewhat, but leads to contradictions when pushed to its consequences.

The problem of self-action of charged sphere on itself was not completely solved, because it involves modelling charged sphere in a way consistent with theory of relativity. Since in theory of relativity the sphere cannot be rigid but has internal degrees of freedom, the model gets very complicated very soon.

There are only approximate theories of charged sphere, search the works of Arthur Yaghjian and Rodrigo Medina.

Feynman and others thought there should be similar self-action term even for point particles, but this is not necessary.

Consistent theories of charged point particles were described many times long time ago, e.g. by Frenkel:

J. Frenkel, Zur Elektrodynamik punktfoermiger Elektronen, Zeits. f. Phys., 32, (1925), p. 518-534.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01331692

In English, this article also explains it concisely:

R. C. Stabler, A Possible Modification of Classical Electrodynamics, Physics Let-
ters, 8, 3, (1964), p. 185-187.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0031-9163(64)91989-4

There is no self-action in this kind of theory.

Comment: According to Google scholar the paper by stabler was cited 3 times since 1964; is this correct? why was it ignored?

Comment: The paper is fine I think. I do not have any other information about the number of citations, but I expect it to be low. The theory these papers (and others, there were many more published with the same main idea) propose is very different from what one learns in the established textbooks. It solves the old problems but beyond that to derive further consequences from it requires quite hard calculations (numerical simulations for many-particle system with retarded interactions).

Comment: Also, the paper is about non-quantum theory, which largely explains why it was ignored. Lots of good ideas get marginalized and forgotten.