Quantization of charge implying charge exist in the form of point particles
The statement for quantization of charge says that total charge of a body is constant. Now the word " body " seems vague. We may consider any part of space which we want and call it a body. Thus the more direct statement is that charge in a given volume of space is quantised. Let's thus call charge in this volume, $q = e×n$, where $n$ is a whole number. Suppose we extend this volume infinitesimally in a given direction. According to the statement (or law) charge will still be quantized in that volume. $n$ may not increase ( case 1) or $n$ may increase by a natural number (case 2). The infinitesimal volume may be as small as we want. This indicates that those whole number of charges occupy just a point as we choose the volume to be 0 thereby predicting the existence of point particles which carry charge.  So saying charge is not point particle means saying quantization of charge is wrong. But we have seen that poynting theorem is contradicting point charges. So what has gone wrong?

To me it looks like your question is mixing classical and quantum concepts all over. I think you should choose one or the other and ask a purely classical or a purely quantum question

Classical Mechanics cannot answer i think because it don't at all support the idea of quantization of charge because it says like charges repel so point charges should disintegrate.  What changes should I make to appear this question more quantum?

Poynting theorem is classical... Actually i think first I should learn quantum mechanics then I should such questions. No need to a answer this question it can be closed.

The Poynting theorem is derived and valid for not too singular charge distributions, including charge distributed in volume and on a surface, but excluding line or point charges. For point particles, the Poynting expressions such as $\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf j$ or $\int E^2 dV$ are mathematically undefined or infinite, and thus can't be consistently used to talk about EM energy. A different theory and theorem interpretable as law of local conservation of energy have to be derived for point charged particles. This has been done in papers by Fokker, Tetrode, Frenkel, and later in Feynman-Wheeler.

See the papers I refer to here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/182454/31895

Also, quantization of charge does not in any way imply the charge exists as points. The charge can exists in very small volumes instead, which we are unable to divide. We use the point particle idea because it is the simplest and very powerful. It fails to fully describe protons, which have non-point charge structure, but so far holds for electrons. In the future, we may find structure in electrons as well, and then point charged particle will become just another case of useful but only approximate idea.

Thx for that piece of information I will read it along with Feynman-wheeler.  You said "charge can exist in very small volumes " . My logic may be wrong somewhere but it says charge "have to exist "  instead of "can exist" in very small volume and there is no limit to the closeness of the volume to 0 unit volumes. Mathematically $V >0$

All these seems very complicated because $V>0$ (very small particle) is not same as $V>=0 $ (point particle). And I have proved the first one not the second one so ok we cannot say it point particle.
